# Why does the triangle rendered by OpenGL ES 2.0 , with SDL 2.0 context, vanishes after a single render, if events are not polled?

Tags: game-loop, opengl-es2, sdl2

I was experimenting with OpenGL ES 2.0 and being new to OpenGL, I was trying to render a simple triangle. But I was shocked to see that, if I **do not** call `SDL_PollEvent(...)` after `glDrawArrays(...)` in the game loop, I see the triangle render on the screen for a split second and then it vanishes altogether ! But, if I call `SDL_PollEvent` then **everything is fine** ! Can anyone explain to me the reason for this abnormal behavior???

However, this is the interesting part of my code:

This code works perfectly, if I **uncomment** the **commented** block of code:

```
uint32_t vbo; 
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);

bool run = true;
SDL_Event e;
while (run)
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window); 

/*while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
      switch(e.type)
      {
           case SDL_QUIT:
                run = false;
                break; 
      }
} */
```

}

Vertex Shader:

```
precision mediump float; 
attribute vec3 pos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0); 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float; 
void main()
{
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
}
```

Every help will be greatly appreciated, Thankyou everyone in advance !

Comment: What platform are you running the code on?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Android

Comment: Not sure if exact reason will make any difference. Program *must* poll events every so often, otherwise OS may (will) decide that program has hung and must be killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is normal. Due to internal structure of the SDL, you are required to call `SDL_PollEvent` or `SDL_PumpEvents` (it is called internally by `SDL_PollEvent`) in your main loop so that SDL event subsystem works as expected. Without this call, your loop is stuck infinitely somethere within SDL waiting for the events to be processed.

See details on the [SDL_PollEvent wiki page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent).

Considering your comment the [SDL_PumpEvents](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) wiki page mentiones that event pumping should be done on the same thread that initialized the video subsystem. So your intent is, unfortunatelly, not compatible with internal architecture of the SDL either. But event pumping is really extra lightweight stuff, not sure if it's worth it anyway.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! My intention was to run the event processing loop as a separate thread, and let OpenGL be part of the ```main``` application. But, that also causes the same problem!

Comment: I've added more information to the answer considering your comment.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer!!! It cleared up everything for me!!! :)

Comment: I want to render some time consuming graphics using OpenGL. Therefore, the rendering process might crash my application if it's unable to poll events... :) That is why, I thought of doing multi threading, but now I **realize** that it is also not possible! So, is there any way around this??? :) How can I make the OpenGL rendering separate, from event handling! I attempted almost everything, but, I can't separate out the event handling part from it! :)